# SimplePie Multiple Feeds Random Order

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed, simplepie

I am new to SimplePie and was looking through the API and couldn't find what I needed. I need to use Simple Pie to get random articles from multiple feeds. I'll better explain my question:

Here's how SimplePie gives me the feed now (in chronological order):

- Article 1 (CNN)
- Article 2 (CNN)
- Article 3 (CNN)
- Article 4 (CNN)
- Article 5 (CNN)
- Article 1 (YAHOO)
- Article 2 (YAHOO)
- Article 3 (YAHOO)
- Article 4 (YAHOO)
- Article 5 (YAHOO)
- Article 1 (GOOGLE)
- Article 2 (GOOGLE)
- Article 3 (GOOGLE)
- Article 4 (GOOGLE)
- Article 5 (GOOGLE)

Here is how I need it (in random order):

- Article 3 (CNN)
- Article 1 (GOOGLE)
- Article 5 (YAHOO)
- Article 3 (GOOGLE)
- Article 2 (CNN)
- Article 4 (YAHOO)
- Article 1 (CNN)
- Article 3 (GOOGLE)
- Article 3 (YAHOO)

and so forth..

As far as I know, I would have to make a separate SimplePie feed everytime just to pull one unique article. I want Simple Pie to be able to do this with one call, but just rearranging them in  before it sends it back. So kind of like a custom resort.

Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question here: [Custom Sort Order with SimplePie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127709/custom-sort-order-with-simplepie/12136636#12136636)

You need to extend the class.

```
class SimplePie_Random_Sort extends SimplePie
{
    public static function sort_items($a, $b)
    {
        return rand(-1, 1);
    }
}
```